# How to use stopword in the preprocessing a txt file

Tags: python, stop-words

I'm  trying to write a code that will text process and eventually index all of them. I first need to remove non-alphabetic characters and punctuation, and convert capital letter to lower case, then remove the stopwords.

Here is what I did so far:

```
from stopwords import *

def removeStopwords(wordlist, flag):
    return [w for w in wordlist if w not in flag]

def preprocessing():
    import re
    with open('44.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as data:
        for line in data:
            a = line.rstrip().lower()
            result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', a)
            b = removeStopwords(result, stopwords)
            print(b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    preprocessing()
```

Then I get all the letters break into parts like
 ['a'], ['w'], ['o'], ['l'], ['f']

stopwords.py is just list of words like:

```
stopwords = ['a', 'are', 'aren t', ....]
```

Can somebody tell me what is going on?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: What's the problem with what you've done so far? What parts work, where does it go wrong, and where are you stuck on fixing it?

Comment: If I remove all the stopwords parts, and do print(result), it works fine. I just don't know how to apply the stopwords from a source appropriately

Answer (score 2):

Wordlist is just a string.When you are doing

```
w for w in wordlist if w not in flag
```

It is iterating over each character of the string ,hence you are getting separate alphabets.Convert `wordlist` into a list before passing to `removeStopwords`.

```
def preprocessing():
    import re
    with open('44.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as data:
        for line in data:
            a = line.rstrip().lower()
            result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', a)
            result = result.split()#creates a list of words
            b = removeStopwords(result, stopwords)
            print(b)
```

Comment: This is the same as jedwards' answer, and it has the exact same problem: none of the words in `result.split()` can possibly match a stopword like `"aren t"`.

Comment: @zakels: No it doesn't. Try it with "These examples aren't good". It won't remove the "aren't".

Comment: @abarnert sorry when I wrote the answer jedwards's answer was not there.. I guess he deleted it while i was writing it.Even now it is not showing..

Comment: @avinashpandey: Yes, he deleted it because of exactly this problem.

Comment: @abarnert I get it ,But I think main problem was why it was returning list of character instead of list of words.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem, as [jedward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29573398/908494) explains, is that, despite the misleading name `wordlist`, what you're passing to `removeStopwords` is not a list of words, it's a string—a sequence of individual characters.

If your stoplist were actually made up entirely of single words, the solution would be simple: split the string into words, then remove the ones that match the stoplist.

Unfortunately, if you have things like `aren t` in the stoplist, that isn't going to work—`"These examples aren't good"` will get preprocessed and split into `"these examples aren t good"`, which will split into `["these", "examples", "aren", "t", "good"]`, and obviously none of those words matches `"aren t"`.

The ideal solution would be to remove intra-word punctuation instead of converting it to spaces. Something like this:

```
result = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', re.sub("['_]", '', a))
```

Then you end up with `"these examples arent good"`, and (assuming you write the stopword as `"arent"` instead of `"aren t"`) the simple solution still works. However, this may not be appropriate for your requirements—it's changing the rules.

So, let's say we can't do that. Then, if you want to keep things simple, you need to actually filter out *subsequences*, not just individual words.

So, something like this:

```
def removeStopwords(line, stopwords):
    result = []
    wordlist = line.split()
    i = 0
    while i < len(wordlist):
        for stopword in stopwords:
            stopwordlist = stopword.split()
            if wordlist[i:i+len(stopwordlist)] == stopwordlist:
                i += len(stopwordlist)
                break
        else:
            result.append(wordlist[i])
            i += 1
    return ' '.join(result)
```

If you need it to be faster, you need to preprocess `stopwords` into a better data structure, like a trie, that can be quickly scanned for matching prefixes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I totally see what the problem is. I didn't notice I had a problem in the stopwords like "aren t" because the next step was to throw out the words of length less than 3. Thanks for the post!